# how to update renderer.text() in highcharts after a graph has been drawn?

Tags: javascript, svg, highcharts

In my application, which uses highcharts lib, i use svg draw function for my chart load/redraw events.

I set all my chart data to equal value so that all the stacks will have same height, while the real data is kept in temp array that is drawn as svg in this way:

```
var dataFormat = getLabelByStatus(curCount, yearsObj[i].data[0]);

                        var css = (point.color == USERS_YEARS_COLOR) ? highchartAttr().dataLabelsBoldStyle : highchartAttr().dataLabelsStyle;

                        //  draw text
                        var text = renderer.text(dataFormat, -9999, -5).add(point.label);

                        text.attr({
                            x: (lineLength - text.getBBox().width) / 3
                        }).css(css)
```

This works great but now i want to change this data in a callback function.
I still can access the renderer object, but neither i can find my old printed data to edit it, nor i can find a suitable edit function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can save your custom text element in a variable or in the chart like this

```
    chart.customText = chart.renderer.text('Series 1', 140, 140)
    .attr({
        rotation: -25
    })
    .css({
        color: '#4572A7',
        fontSize: '16px'
    })
    .add();
```

Then you can access it and use `attr({text})` to change its text

```
chart.customText.attr({
  text: Math.random()
})
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/28nwb7pj/

Answer (score 1):

Actually i found a bypass solution for this.
In the draw function, i added an id attribute so later on it is easy to get it with jquery selector and edit it with .text().

```
text.attr({
                            x: (lineLength - text.getBBox().width) / 3,
                            id: 'text_' + i // id added to make it modifiable
                        }).css(css)
```

change text example in callback function:

`$('#text_2').children().text(435)`